# How can I change a path of a file properties (for Gate Benchmark)?

Tags: java, properties, gate

I am new user of Gate.
I try to use a fonction "Benchmark" of Gate which require a file .properties.
The manual said that I have to save this file in a folder which a message said.

> The properties of the corpus benchmark tool are defined in the file
> ‘corpus_tool.properties’, which should be located in the GATE home
> directory. GATE will tell you where it’s looking for the properties
> file in the ‘message’ panel when you run the Corpus Benchmark Tool.

The problem is that a path required in the message is the system folder. The message is like that :

> Evaluating human-marked documents against pre-stored results. Loading
> properties from /corpus_tool.properties /corpus_tool.properties does
> not exist, using default settings

And of course, I can not save the file in the system folder.
So I want to know a way to change a path that Gate Benchmark required.

If anyone can give me any advise, it will be very helpful.
Thanks.